# How to get a Continuous Position on a Google Static Map?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps-mobile

I live in Monterey, CA and I own a Android smart phone. I created a webpage with [Google Static Map Wizard](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/simplewizard/makestaticmap.html) and wanted to watch myself walk around town on my new phone by viewing the webpage on the phone. Is it possible to display a marker on the static map of my current (on the move) location? I am really into myself and would like to watch myself walk around town.

This is the code that I got out of the map wizard. Any help or direction would be very appreciated. I am not sure how to add the current location?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    
/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=36.595914,-121.887295&
zoom=16&format=png&sensor=false&size=400x500&maptype=hybrid" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried yourself?

You can create an Android application that sends your current location to a web application, which can then modify the Google Maps image URL to include a marker at the specified location.

Another solution is using [HTML5's Geolocation](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) to add another marker to the map at your location. (Search for more information about this) This way you can avoid the need of server-side software, as everything can be done with HTML5 and JavaScript.

At any rate; it's a bit more complicated than just a static page with a map on it, so try to do some research first!

Good luck!